# Steinhaus Theorem proof on Wikipedia

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I would like help understanding [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20the%20mathematical%20field%20of,first%20proved%20by%20Hugo%20Steinhaus.) of the Steinhaus Theorem.

I have two questions:

1. In the proof, they claim that there exists an interval $\Delta =(a,b)$ containing E so that $m(E)>\alpha (b-a)$. Can someone justify the validity of this claim?
2. In the proof, they allow $m(E)$ to be infinite. Why doesn't the proof break-down in this case?

I've already thought a bit about this:
I know that there exists an open set $U$ containing $E$ so that $m(U)<m(E)+\varepsilon$. But, in the notation of the proof linked above, how is the interval $\Delta$ found? Is it some union relating to $U$?